# Physics Engine for WPF

Tags: wpf, physics, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm looking for a 2D physics engine for WPF, not Silverlight. The physics engine should be blendable so that I can specify in blend a behavior of a specific control. Are there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only game in town is the [Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) in combination with the [Physics Helper](http://physicshelper.codeplex.com/) and they are only properly supported for Silverlight.  The main problem seems to be a lack of motivated users wanting WPF support.  Your only real option is to port `Physics Helper` to WPF.  It's been [done before](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Default.aspx?tabid=67&EntryID=166) so you can use the old version if you can find it or do it again.